# The width of a pavement around a building is uniform. The pavement is equal to 8500m$^2$ and the building is 120m by 80m.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

The width of a pavement around a building is uniform. The pavement is equal to 8500m$^2$ and the building is 120m by 80m. What is the width between the building and pavement?

I mapped it out and I can't seem to get it. I'm in grade 11 math.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the area of the building? If the width of the pavement is $x$, can you express the area of the pavement in terms of $x$?

Comment: Area of the building is 120x80 so 9600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pavement width is $w$. The rectangle formed by the pavement (including building) has an area $A=(120+2w)\cdot(80+2w)$. You also know $A-120\cdot80=8500$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I know how to factor it but I don't know the second part of the equation. Can you please expand.

Comment: Which equation? There are two

Comment: $A-120*80=8500$

Comment: $A$ is the area of pavement and building combined. You know the area of the pavement only (8500) and the area of the building ($80\cdot120$). Sum them together and you get $A$

Comment: Okay so $A=18100$?

Comment: Yes. So all you need to do now is to solve the quadratic equation

Comment: What do you mean? I factored out $A=(120+2w)(80+2w)$ to get $4w^2+400w+9600$ but I still don't understand where to go to next

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83659/discussion-between-andrei-and-zebert).